# Magento - Hidden value not set in grid serializer

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I'm developing an extension for magento which display question groups from custom database table and I need to assign questions(which is loaded from another custom table ), to groups.

So far I could code the grid to display question groups, and questions. When I go to edit one question group, it displays all the questions there in the database. What I need is to select some of them and save. If I load all the questions to one screen ( so far I have 130 questions and I can load all of them to one screen by changing "view 20 per page" to read "view 200 per page" in the grid) and select what I need, and then save, it works as a charm.

But if I select some questions from page 1 and navigate to 2nd page and then select some other questions, and so on, Only the questions in the last page are saved. And all the other selections in the previous pages are lost.

I found that the hidden value of the grid serialize is overridden each time I navigate through pages so selections are lost.

Any advice is greatly appreciate.

Here is the code I used
app\code\community\Muaw\Prescription\Block\Adminhtml\Groups\Edit\Tab\Question.php

```
    class Muaw_Prescription_Block_Adminhtml_Groups_Edit_Tab_Question extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('questionsGrid');
    $this->setUseAjax(true);
    $this->setDefaultFilter(array('in_questions' => 1));
    $this->setSaveParametersInSession(false);
}

protected function _addColumnFilterToCollection($column)
{
    if ($column->getId() == 'in_questions') {
        $questionIds = $this->_getSelectedQuestions();
        if (empty($questionIds)) {
            $questionIds = 0;
        }
        if ($column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
            $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('id', array('in' => $questionIds));
        } else {
            if ($questionIds) {
                $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('id', array('nin' => $questionIds));
            }
        }
    } else {
        parent::_addColumnFilterToCollection($column);
    }
    return $this;
}

protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getModel('muaw_prescription/question')->getCollection();
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}

protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $this->addColumn('in_questions', array(
        'header_css_class' => 'a-center',
        'type' => 'checkbox',
        'name' => 'in_questions',
        'field_name' => 'questions[]',
        'values' => $this->_getSelectedQuestions(),
        'align' => 'center',
        'index' => 'id'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('id', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('ID'),
        'sortable' => true,
        'width' => '60',
        'index' => 'id'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('question', array(
        'header' => $this->__('Question'),
        'index' => 'question',
        'align' => 'left',
    ));

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}

protected function _getSelectedQuestions()
{
    $customers = array_keys($this->getSelectedQuestions());
    return $customers;
}

public function getSelectedQuestions()
{
    $tm_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    if (!isset($tm_id)) {
        $tm_id = 0;
    }
    $questions = array();
    $groupq = Mage::getModel('muaw_prescription/qgr')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('group_id', $tm_id);
    foreach ($groupq as $group) {
        $questions[] = $group->getQuestionId();
    }
    $custIds = array();

    foreach ($questions as $cust) {
        $custIds[$cust] = array('id' => $cust);
    }
    return $custIds;
}

public function getGridUrl()
{
    return $this->_getData('grid_url') ? $this->_getData('grid_url') : $this->getUrl('*/*/questionsGrid', array('_current' => true));
}
}
```

app\code\community\Muaw\Prescription\Block\Adminhtml\Groups\Edit\Tabs.php

```
class Muaw_Prescription_Block_Adminhtml_Groups_Edit_Tabs extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs
{
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('form_tabs');
    $this->setDestElementId('edit_form');
    $this->setTitle(Mage::helper('muaw_prescription')->__('Group Information'));
}


protected function _beforeToHtml()
{
    $this->addTab('form_section', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('muaw_prescription')->__('Groups Information'),
        'title' => Mage::helper('muaw_prescription')->__('Details'),
        'content' => $this->getLayout()
            ->createBlock('muaw_prescription/adminhtml_groups_edit_tab_main')
            ->toHtml(),
    ));

    $this->addTab('questions', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('muaw_prescription')->__('Associated Questions'),
        'url' => $this->getUrl('*/*/questionstab', array('_current' => true)),
        'content' => $this->getLayout(),
        'class' => 'ajax',
    ));
    return parent::_beforeToHtml();
}
}
```

app\code\community\Muaw\Prescription\controllers\Adminhtml\GroupsController.php

```
class Muaw_Prescription_Adminhtml_GroupsController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
protected function _initAction()
{
    // load layout, set active menu and breadcrumbs
    $this->loadLayout()
        ->_setActiveMenu('prescription/manage')
        ->_addBreadcrumb(
            Mage::helper('muaw_prescription')->__('Group'),
            Mage::helper('muaw_prescription')->__('Group')
        )
        ->_addBreadcrumb(
            Mage::helper('muaw_prescription')->__('Manage Group'),
            Mage::helper('muaw_prescription')->__('Manage Group')
        );
    return $this;
}

public function indexAction()
{
    $this->_title($this->__('Group'))
        ->_title($this->__('Manage Group'));

    $this->_initAction();
    $this->renderLayout();
}

public function QuestionAction()
{
    $this->_title($this->__('Group Questions'))
        ->_title($this->__('Manage Group Questions'));

    $this->loadLayout()
        ->_setActiveMenu('groups/manage')
        ->_addBreadcrumb(
            Mage::helper('muaw_prescription')->__('Group Questions'),
            Mage::helper('muaw_prescription')->__('Group Questions')
        )
        ->_addBreadcrumb(
            Mage::helper('muaw_prescription')->__('Manage Group Questions'),
            Mage::helper('muaw_prescription')->__('Manage Group Questions')
        );
    $this->renderLayout();
}

public function newAction()
{
    // the same form is used to create and edit
    $this->_forward('edit');
}

public function editAction()
{
    $this->_title($this->__('Group'))
        ->_title($this->__('Manage Group'));

    $model = Mage::getModel('muaw_prescription/groups');

    $newsId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    if ($newsId) {
        $model->load($newsId);

        if (!$model->getId()) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError(Mage::helper('muaw_prescription')->__('Group does not exist.'));
            return $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        }
        $this->_title($model->getTitle());
        $breadCrumb = Mage::helper('muaw_prescription')->__('Edit Item');
    } else {
        $this->_title(Mage::helper('muaw_prescription')->__('New Item'));
        $breadCrumb = Mage::helper('muaw_prescription')->__('New Item');
    }

    $this->_initAction()->_addBreadcrumb($breadCrumb, $breadCrumb);

    $data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getFormData(true);
    if (!empty($data)) {
        $model->addData($data);
    }

    Mage::register('question_item', $model);

    $this->renderLayout();
}

public function saveAction()
{
    $redirectPath = '*/*';
    $redirectParams = array();

    // check if data sent
    $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

    if (isset($data['links'])) {
        $customers = Mage::helper('adminhtml/js')->decodeGridSerializedInput($data['links']['questions']);
    }
    //print_r($customers);exit;
    if ($data) {

        $data = $this->_filterPostData($data);
        $model = Mage::getModel('muaw_prescription/groups');

        if (empty($data['pid'])) {
            $arr = array();
            $arr['form_key'] = $data['form_key'];
            $arr['name'] = $data['name'];
            $model->addData($arr);
            $out = $model->save()->getId();
        } else {
            $arr = array();
            $arr['form_key'] = $data['form_key'];
            $arr['id'] = $data['pid'];
            $arr['name'] = $data['name'];
            $model->load($data['pid'])->addData($arr);
            $model->setId($data['pid'])->save();
            $out = $data['pid'];
        }

        try {
            $hasError = false;
            $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(Mage::helper('muaw_prescription')->__('The Group has been saved.'));
            // check if 'Save and Continue'
            if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                $redirectPath = '*/*/edit';
                $redirectParams = array('id' => $out);
            }


            $groupq = Mage::getModel('muaw_prescription/qgr')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('group_id', $out);
            $sel_question = array();
            foreach ($groupq as $group) {
                if (!empty($group->getQuestionId())) {
                    $sel_question[$group->getId()] = $group->getQuestionId();
                }
            }

            $del_arr = $new_arr = array();
            $del_arr = array_diff($sel_question, $data['questions']);
            $new_arr = array_diff($data['questions'], $sel_question);

            if (!empty($data['questions'])) {
                if (!empty($del_arr)) {
                    foreach ($del_arr as $del => $val) {
                        $id = $del;
                        $model_qgr = Mage::getModel('muaw_prescription/qgr');
                        try {
                            $model_qgr->setId($id)->delete();
                        } catch (Exception $e) {
                            //echo $e->getMessage();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $collection = Mage::getModel('muaw_prescription/qgr')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('group_id', $out);
                foreach ($collection as $item) {
                    $id = $item->getId();
                    $model_qgr = Mage::getModel('muaw_prescription/qgr');
                    try {
                        $model_qgr->setId($id)->delete();
                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                        //echo $e->getMessage();
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!empty($new_arr)) {
                foreach ($new_arr as $new) {
                    if ($new != 'on') {
                        $new_data = array();
                        $new_data['question_id'] = $new;
                        $new_data['group_id'] = $out;
                        try {
                            $model_qgr = Mage::getModel('muaw_prescription/qgr')->setData($new_data);
                            $insertId = $model_qgr->save()->getId();
                        } catch (Exception $e) {
                            //echo $e->getMessage();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {

            }
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $hasError = true;
            $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $hasError = true;
            $this->_getSession()->addException($e, Mage::helper('muaw_prescription')->__('An error occurred while saving the Group.'));
        }
        if ($hasError) {
            $this->_getSession()->setFormData($data);
            $redirectPath = '*/*/edit';
            $redirectParams = array('id' => $data['pid']);
        }
    }
    $this->_redirect($redirectPath, $redirectParams);
}

public function deleteAction()
{
    // check if we know what should be deleted
    $itemId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    if ($itemId) {
        try {
            $model = Mage::getModel('muaw_prescription/groups');
            $model->load($itemId);
            if (!$model->getId()) {
                Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('muaw_prescription')->__('Unable to find a group.'));
            }
            $model->delete();

            $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                Mage::helper('muaw_prescription')->__('The group has been deleted.')
            );
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addException($e,
                Mage::helper('muaw_prescription')->__('An error occurred while deleting the group.')
            );
        }
    }
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
}

protected function _initGroups()
{
    $groupModel = Mage::getModel('muaw_prescription/groups');
    $groupId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('id', 0);
    if ($groupId) {
        try {
            $groupModel->load($groupId);
            if (!$groupModel->getId()) {
                throw new Exception($this->__('This group no longer exists'));
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }

    Mage::register('current_group', $groupModel);
    return $groupModel;
}

protected function _isAllowed()
{
    switch ($this->getRequest()->getActionName()) {
        case 'new':
        case 'save':
            return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('groups/manage/save');
            break;
        case 'delete':
            return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('groups/manage/delete');
            break;
        default:
            return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('groups/manage');
            break;
    }
}

protected function _filterPostData($data)
{
    $data = $this->_filterDates($data, array('time_published'));
    return $data;
}

public function gridAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}

protected function _isAjax()
{
    if ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        return true;
    }
    if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('ajax') || $this->getRequest()->getParam('isAjax')) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


public function questionsTabAction()
{

    $itemId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $groupq = Mage::getModel('muaw_prescription/qgr')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('group_id', $itemId);
    $sel_question = array();
    foreach ($groupq as $group) {
        if (!empty($group->getQuestionId())) {
            $sel_question[] = $group->getQuestionId();
        }
    }

    $saved_question_ids = $sel_question; // your load logic here

    if (!empty($saved_question_ids)) {
        $this->loadLayout()
            ->getLayout()
            ->getBlock('muaw.tab.questions')
            ->setQuestions($saved_question_ids);
    } else {
        $this->loadLayout()
            ->getLayout()
            ->getBlock('muaw.tab.questions')
            ->setQuestions($this->getRequest()->getPost('questions', null));
    }

    $this->renderLayout();
}

public function questionsGridAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout()
        ->getLayout()
        ->getBlock('muaw.tab.questions')
        ->setQuestions($this->getRequest()->getPost('questions', null));

    $this->renderLayout();
}

public function questionsAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('muaw.tab.questions')
        ->setQuestions($this->getRequest()->getPost('questions', null));
    $this->renderLayout();
}
}
```

app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout\muaw_prescription.xml

```
<adminhtml_groups_edit>
    <update handle="editor"/>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="muaw_prescription/adminhtml_groups_edit_tabs" name="groups.edit.tabs" />
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="muaw_prescription/adminhtml_groups_edit" name="groups.edit" />
    </reference>
</adminhtml_groups_edit>

<adminhtml_groups_questionstab>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="root" output="toHtml">
        <block type="muaw_prescription/adminhtml_groups_edit_tab_question" name="muaw.tab.questions"/>
        <block type="adminhtml/widget_grid_serializer" name="muaw.serializer.questions">
            <reference name="muaw.serializer.questions">
                <action method="initSerializerBlock">
                    <grid_block_name>muaw.tab.questions</grid_block_name>
                    <data_callback>getSelectedQuestions</data_callback>
                    <hidden_input_name>links[questions]</hidden_input_name>
                    <reload_param_name>questions</reload_param_name>
                </action>
                <action method="addColumnInputName">
                    <input_name>position</input_name>
                </action>
                </reference>
        </block>
    </block>
</adminhtml_groups_questionstab>

<adminhtml_groups_questionsgrid>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="root">
        <block type="muaw_prescription/adminhtml_groups_edit_tab_question" name="muaw.tab.questions"/>
    </block>
</adminhtml_groups_questionsgrid>
```

Comment: Who us your code? How can we hope to solve anything without it?

Comment: Sorry, I updated question with the code I used